# Regex: How to split and replace a string that contains numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, split

I need a regex to add an asterisk (`*`) at the beginning and at the end of a word or group of words, except numbers that are alone. Any number that has a letter next to it is okay. It's hard to explain, but here we have some examples:

```
123 Ballister 1 Block           --> 123 *Ballister* 1 *Block*

B@llister Place 123 Block N2 45 --> *B@llister Place* 123 *Block N2* 45

123 B@llister# abc              --> 123 *B@llister# abc*
```

I tried with:

```js
var sample = "@sample 22 @sample2 xyz1";
var x = sample.replace(/[^0-9 ]+/g, function(str) {
    return "*"+str.trim()+"*";
});
```

but it is not working. I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: How come `N2` is valid?

Comment: Any word or group of words are valid examples to add the asterisks, for example:

N2,
This is a test,
This is a test #01,
abc123

Those are example of words or group of words that include numbers or characters that I need to add the asterisk at the beginning and in the end of the match, excluding numbers that are alone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example that works:

```
/((?!\d+\b)\S(?:\S| \D)*)/
```

The replacement string is just

```
*$1*
```

[Here's a demo](https://regex101.com/r/sR8cP7/2).

The examples work like this:

```
123 Ballister 1 Block
--> 123 *Ballister* 1 *Block*

B@llister Place 123 Block N2 45
--> *B@llister Place* 123 *Block N2* 45

123 B@llister# abc
--> 123 *B@llister# abc*

@rmani empory 123
--> *@rmani empory* 123

#1smple 22 #sample2 #xyz1
--> *#1smple* 22 *#sample2 #xyz1*
```

## Explanation

We want to match whole words or groups of words, but exclude words that are made entirely of digits. So...

- `(` start capturing

  - `(?!\d+\b)` don't match an entire word of numbers
  - `\S` require a non-space character (so we don't match like `* def*` in `abc def`)
  - `(?:\S| \D)` either a non-space character or a space and a non-digit
  - `*` zero or more times
- `)` stop capturing

## Putting it All Together

You can use this as follows:

```
var sample = "@sample 22 @sample2 xyz1";
var x = sample.replace(/((?!\d+\b)\S(?:\S| \D)*)/g, '*$1*');
```

## Live Demo:

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0],
        output = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];

input.onkeyup = function (elem) {
    output.innerHTML = input.value.replace(/((?!\d+\b)\S(?:\S| \D)*)/g, '*$1*');
};
```

```html
<p>
    Original Text: <input />
</p>
<p>
    Replacement: <span />
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ed! It was almost what I needed! It's failing only in the following cases:

@rmani empory 123  // exp result: \*@rmani empory\* 123
#1smple 22 #sample2 #xyz1 // exp result: \*#1smple\* 22 \*#sample2 #xyz1\*

Comment: I really appreciate your help

Comment: I forgot to add the case of special characters at the beginning of a word or group of words in my original question, sorry about that, I hope you can help me because I really suck in regular expressions

Comment: I took care of the @-at-the-beginning issue, looks like this: ((@|)\b(?!\b\d+\b)\S(?:\S| \D)*) and is also as an edit in the revised answer

Comment: @StefanDochow You may ***NOT*** edit code. Use the comments to post comments; do not change the post.

Comment: @ed sorry, weren't people doing that to my posts too? I thought I was supposed to do it this way. my bad. won't happen again.

Comment: @StefanDochow You may edit posts to fix misspellings, grammar mistakes, bad formatting, and so on. You may not change the meaning of the post or modify how a piece of code works. If anyone did that to one of your posts, the edit should have been rejected. The rule is that even if an answer is completely broken and a single character change in the code would fix it, that's out of bounds. Instead, you can leave a comment and point out the problem.

Comment: @StefanDochow No problem.

Comment: @EdCottrell Thank you very much! it worked! it really worked! I really appreciate your time and effort Mr. Ed :)

Comment: @MiguelReyes Glad to help! It was an interesting question. :)

Comment: @EdCottrell , one more question... How do you get to be as good in regex? is there a resource or book that you recommend to me? or practice makes the master? hehe

Comment: @MiguelReyes Just practice! Lots and lots of practice. http://regex101.com is one very helpful site for practicing, but there are lots of others, too.